# Why shouldn't children be passed as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

According to ESLINT rule [no-children-prop](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-children-prop.md)

> When using JSX, the children should be nested between the opening
>   and closing tags. When not using JSX, the children should be passed as
>   additional arguments to React.createElement

Is this just a style suggestion, or can real damage arise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be more of a stylistic suggestion and also prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.

If you had a component:

```
<Component children="foo">bar</Component>
```

and in the component do

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.props.children}
  </div>
)
```

you would end up getting `bar` as `this.props.children` instead of `foo` but as far as this breaking anything in react or causing "damage"
I have found no evidence of such and there is a lengthy discussions here https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1089#issuecomment-250640742
stating the same.