# How do I allow have a component to have variable child components without using props.children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read the docs on [no-children-prop](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-children-prop.md) and similar questions like: [Why shouldn't children be passed as a prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982416/why-shouldnt-children-be-passed-as-a-prop) but I'm still not sure of the correct syntax to use children inside a react component.

For example, if I previously had:

```js
export default function SomeComponent({...props}){
  return (
    <button 
      <span className="greeting">{props.children}</span>
    </button>
  );
}
```

The [eslint page](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-children-prop.md) seems to only have examples not using JSX. Searching elsewhere only seems to give examples of using `props.children`

**How do I allow have a component to have variable child components without using `props.children`?**

Comment: You can render them conditionally in the JSX itself, you can use use a switch case block too if the conditions are more

Comment: OK but how does the parent component pass the child component the grandchildren that were previously in `props.children`?